# How can I get a feminine body?

Tags: weight-loss, exercise, gym

I'm a newbie here, so please forgive me if such kind of a question has already been answered.
So, I'm a male. Yeah, I might get a lot of backlash for this one, but I'll cut to the chase. I want a feminine body, meaning, I want bigger hips and slimmer upper body. I really don't know if I can achieve something like that without any deviations from my original plan, but asking is not penalized, is it. What kind of exercises should I take on? Do I need a specific diet?
If any additional information is necessary, I might share it with you.

Comment: Specifically about "bigger hips": There probably is very little (if anything) that you can do to change the dimensions of your pelvis and femurs; however, squatting can help strengthen/grow the muscles of the hips and legs, which may achieve satisfactory changes in your appearance.

Answer (score 1):

**Diet**

No, there's no food that will make you more feminine, unless you're looking to change your hormones.

If you want a slimmer figure, you likely want to lose weight. In that case, regular procedures for weight loss apply.

**Exercise**

At this point, you're going to have to set a goal for each part of your body, and create/get a workout program for these particular goals.

It's likely that a visit to a personal trainer might be more beneficial, but if you add to the list of goals, we might also be able to help you set up a program.

Comment: Hahah, of course I knew there's no food that'd make me more feminine, obviously I was talking about weightloss. :D And for goals, I'm not quite sure about specifications. Really just a flat stomach and bigger hips. Not sure if there can be anything else to it.

Comment: For the record, that's not what I said, @xPeke. I believe that the asker's notion of shaping your body through exercise and dietting can yield those results to a certain degree. What I said was that there's no particular type of food that will help you do this, unless you put in the exercise.

Comment: Fine comment deleted, reword your answer for future misinterpretations

Comment: I'm not worried about future misinterpretations. The sentence is under "Diet", and has the words "there's no food that will make you more feminine" in it.